# Php/Jquery add rows while looping through data

Tags: php, jquery

I have a database with "7" user account objects.

I have called the objects using any of the loop functions.

```
foreach (objects as object) {
  echo '<div class="col-4>"'.object->property.'"</div>';
}
```

I want to add rows for each 3 columns as they are being displayed.

The above code would result in all my objects/colums/divs being nested in one row.
I want a way in which I can have the loop adding a row for every 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the objects as you go. If $x divided by 3 has no remainder, close and open the next div:

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($objects as $object){
    $x ++;
    echo '<div class="col-4">"'.$object->property.'"</div>';
    echo ($x % 3 == 0) ? '</div><div class="row">' : '';
}
```